# CREATE VIEW of two tables with unique rows

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to CREATE VIEW of two tables, merge them, where column from table1 != column from table2 and later insert the rows that do not have duplicate columns.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test(Birds, Animals, Air, Earth);
INSERT INTO test VALUES("Crow", "Dog", "Oxygen", "Not Flat");

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test1 (Birds, Animals, Air, Earth, Sky);
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES("Crow", "Dog", "Oxygen", "Not Flat", "Blue");
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES("Eagle", "Dog", "Oxygen", "Not Flat", "Blue");

CREATE VIEW view_name AS SELECT * FROM test, test1 WHERE test.Birds != test1.Birds'
```

test Table:

```
Birds|Animals|Air|Earth
Crow|Dog|Oxygen|Not Flat
```

test1 Table:

```
Birds|Animals|Air|Earth|Sky
Crow|Dog|Oxygen|Not Flat|Blue
Eagle|Dog|Oxygen|Not Flat|Blue
```

Current output:

```
Birds|Animals|Air|Earth|Birds:1|Animals:1|Air:1|Earth:1|Sky
Crow|Dog|Oxygen|Not Flat|Eagle|Dog|Oxygen|Not Flat|Blue
```

Desired output:

```
Birds|Animals|Air|Earth|Sky
Eagle|Dog|Oxygen|Not Flat|Blue
```

Comment: `SELECT Birds, Animals, Air, Earth FROM test1 EXCEPT SELECT Birds, Animals, Air, Earth FROM test`? Not clear exactly which columns you want matched

Comment: Error: near "Birds": syntax error    | Want to match Birds

Comment: Sorry edited. But noticed you want the `Sky` column which is not present in `test`. So try `SELECT Birds, Animals, Air, Earth, Sky FROM test1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT test1.Birds, test1.Animals, test1.Air, test1.Earth EXCEPT SELECT test.Birds, test.Animals, test.Air, test.Earth FROM test)`

Comment: This one works perfectly fine! I think I can shorten that to: SELECT * FROM test1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT Birds EXCEPT SELECT Birds FROM test);

Comment: I see that it puts a priority on test1 table yeah? That every column from test1 would be used.

Comment: I said depends what columns you wanted, not clear. Best to use specific table names in the subquery. You can also flip this round `NOT EXISTS...INTERSECT` same result. Yes that gives only rows from `test1`. If you want `test` also then you will have  to `UNION` two separate queries

Comment: Great, that's the solution! Maybe you could post it as a solution? I will accept it as one.

Comment: Done that for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends exactly which columns you want to compare. If it's just the one column, you can do this:

```sql
SELECT Birds, Animals, Air, Earth, Sky
FROM test1
WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT test1.Birds
    EXCEPT
    SELECT test.Birds
    FROM test);
```

You can also flip this round to `NOT EXISTS...INTERSECT` and get the same result.

---

This can also be rewritten as an `EXISTS ... =`:

```
SELECT Birds, Animals, Air, Earth, Sky
FROM test1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM test
    WHERE test.Birds = test1.Birds );
```

---

If you need also the opposing results from `test` you can do the same thing in reverse, then `UNION` the result.

Comment: okay great the exist function gives me ability to retrieve unique object or vice versa from tables?

Comment: It returns a boolean result telling you whether there is any rows in the subquery. You can use this anywhere. We have used it in the `WHERE` to filter. If you only want distinct rows out of the main table `SELECT` then use `SELECT DISTINCT`

Answer (score 0):

You can solve that problem in different ways. However, I have a solution for you. Please check the query and let me know =>

```
DECLARE @test TABLE(Birds VARCHAR(50), Animals VARCHAR(50), Air VARCHAR(50), Earth VARCHAR(50)) ;
INSERT INTO @test VALUES('Crow', 'Dog', 'Oxygen', 'Not Flat');

DECLARE @test1 TABLE (Birds VARCHAR(50), Animals VARCHAR(50), Air VARCHAR(50), Earth VARCHAR(50),Sky VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO @test1 VALUES('Crow', 'Dog', 'Oxygen', 'Not Flat', 'Blue');
INSERT INTO @test1 VALUES('Eagle', 'Dog', 'Oxygen', 'Not Flat', 'Blue');

CREATE VIEW view_name AS
SELECT t1.* FROM @test t 
INNER JOIN @test1 t1 ON t.Birds<>t1.Birds
```

**NOTE:** This code is written in SQL Server.